# How to create a regex for the following scenario?

Tags: regex, grails, groovy

I am currently constructing my matches using regex. I wanted to accept alphanumeric and special characters like period (.), comma (,) and dash (-) only. This is my code:

```
code nullable: false, blank: false, maxSize: 30, matches : /^[0-9a-zA-Z,.-]+?[0-9a-zA-Z ]+?[0-9a-zA-Z,.-]*?$/
```

This code works fine, but every time I entered a combination of a single letter and one of the specified special characters, an error message is thrown.

Example:

```
1) A. (an error is thrown)
2) A- (an error is thrown)
3) A, (an error is thrown)
```

The above example should be a valid input. How will I trim down my regex to allow the given examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A.` is matched by `[0-9a-zA-Z,.-]+?` but the middle part `[0-9a-zA-Z ]+?` does't match anything.

To just match alphanumerics and period, comma and dash, `/^[0-9a-zA-Z,.-]+$/` would be sufficient.

Comment: I can highly recommend Rubular for testing regular expressions: http://rubular.com/r/88GjUT2YsR

Comment: thank you so much for sharing that link Stefan! It is really a great help!